# how to make linux mint Charger Disconnect Notify?

Tags: linux-mint

i am using linux mint 17 cinnamon , well somehow i have some problemes in my laptop charger , i like my panel to be hidden so it's hard to watch if the charger is connected or not .

is there any way to configure or create a script or something to notify me if my charger is disconnected ?

Answer (score 1):

Run this script at background:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :;do
    (( $(</sys/class/power_supply/ADP0/online) )) || notify-send offline
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: sleep 1 will make my laptop in sleep mode ?  then how to save this script to be rune automatically  ?

Comment: help i pasted the script , i've notifications even charger is connected ... notify me eight time before close it and every time write this message as output `bash: /sys/class/power_supply/ADP0/online: No such file or directory`

Comment: then find your location of this file. kernel 4.8 uses this location.